# Ubuntu Jenkins on IBM Cloud Virtual Server for VPC Active (exited)

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, ibm-cloud

I have installed Jenkins on an IBM Cloud Virtual Server (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) for VPC which is exposed publicly with a Floating IP. The status of jenkins is **active (exited)** and I am unable to access the UI through port 8080 to perform the initial setup (mentioned as some people have still been able to access the UI in this situation).

Current status of the jenkins service:

```
jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2021-09-29 21:33:52 UTC; 8min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 10354 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 29 21:33:51 jenkins-server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Sep 29 21:33:51 jenkins-server jenkins[10354]: Correct java version found
Sep 29 21:33:51 jenkins-server jenkins[10354]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Sep 29 21:33:51 jenkins-server su[10393]: (to jenkins) root on none
Sep 29 21:33:51 jenkins-server su[10393]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Sep 29 21:33:51 jenkins-server su[10393]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user jenkins
Sep 29 21:33:52 jenkins-server jenkins[10354]:    ...done.
Sep 29 21:33:52 jenkins-server systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

Memory does not appear to be an issue as `journalctl` does not contain any instances of *oom-killer*; I have ensured that the jenkins user owns all relevant files: */var/lib/jenkins, /var/cache/jenkins, /var/log/jenkins*; I have ensured that the port is set to 8080 in */etc/defaults/jenkins* as well as trying other ports; I have tried enabling *ufw* and allowing port 8080 which just blocked others accessing the server through SSH (have since disabled *ufw*); I have even tried updating Jenkins, but as this is a fresh install this resolved nothing as expected.

The Jenkins log shows that Jenkins is fully up an running, so I am currently at a loss as to how to resolve the issue. Jenkins logs:

```
2021-09-29 21:34:14.364+0000 [id=31]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2021-09-29 21:34:14.381+0000 [id=22]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Is there something else I could try that I haven't yet or is it possible I have just overlooked something simple?